# Record Video in Android with a watermark

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am creating an application to take a video from the front camera and add a logo and save it. 
I read about FFmpeg and have used it Linux. Is there any simple ways present to do the same. 
I have already coded the application.I am trying to add a Frame to the video while taking/saving.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ffmpeg library in Android also.

Often the easiest way is to use one of the well supported wrapper libraries - this one is a good example:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

The wrappers basically wrap an interface around there command line ffmpeg tool, which has the advantage that you can use the same syntax, and leverage the support and Q&A on the web around it.

The disadvantage is that the command line tool was not originally designed to be used this way, but if you use a well supported wrapper you will likely find a lot of the problems have been ironed out.